how to solve $y'=\frac{y-1}{x+2}+\tan{\frac{2y+x}{x+2}}$
I have worked on some equations in my research and i arrived at this differntial equation $y'=\frac{y-1}{x+2}+\tan{\frac{2y+x}{x+2}}$ so can anyone help me to solve it?

let $x=v-2$, $y=u+1$ this would make this a homogeneous equation and then let $u=v*t$ solve in terms of $t,v$ and them write the solution in terms of $x,y$

We have $$y'=\tan\left(\frac{2\,y-2}{x+2}+1\right)+\dfrac{y-1}{x+2}$$
Substitue $y=y_1+1$ and $x=x_1-2$. This is nothing but shifting of origin. So now we have, $$y_{1}'=\tan\left(\frac{2\,y_{1}+x_{1}}{x_{1}}\right)+\dfrac{y_{1}}{x_{1}}$$
Now substitute, $y_1=ux_1$ and rewrite $y_1'$ as $\frac{dy_1}{dx_1}$. So now we have,
$$u\,\mathrm{d}x_{1}+x_{1}\,\mathrm{d}u=\left(\tan\left(2\,u+1\right)+u\right)\,\mathrm{d}x_{1}$$ $$\implies x_{1}\,\mathrm{d}u=\tan\left(2\,u+1\right)\,\mathrm{d}x_{1}$$
$$\implies \cot\left(2\,u+1\right)\,\mathrm{d}u=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x_{1}}{x_{1}}$$
But here is a catch, we have lost the solution  $ u+\dfrac{1}{2}=0\rightarrow \dfrac{y-1}{x+2}+\dfrac{1}{2}=0\rightarrow{x=-2\,y}$, we will adjust it later
Now solving the separable DE yields $$\dfrac{\ln\left(\sin\left(2\,u+1\right)\right)}{2}=\ln\left(x_{1}\right)+C_1$$ Undo all substitutions and write $C_1$ as $\ln(C)$, we will get $$\boxed{\sqrt{\sin\left(\frac{2\,y+x}{x+2}\right)}=C\,\left(x+2\right)}$$
This is the final solution. Observe that the solution, $x=-2y$ is included in the general solution at $C=0$
